# Is there a simple solution to replicate data from SQL Server Azure to PostgreSQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database, database-replication

I need to regularly (but incrementally) sync (one way) the contents of a set of SQL Server Azure tables to a PostgreSQL Azure instance.

Here are some of the avenues I've considered:

- Linked server from SQL Server.  No go.  Apparently Azure doesn't support linked servers.
- Foreign Data Wrapper from PostgreSQL.  No go.  PostgreSQL on Azure only supports the postgres_fdw, not the needed tds_fdw.
- Azure Data Factory.  No go.  The data copy process doesn't work incrementally, and the sink pipeline component doesn't support PosgreSQL.
- Commercial replication solutions.  Too expensive for a startup and most aren't hosted.
- SymmetricDS or ReplicaDB.  These might work, but aren't hosted so we may or may not save time over building a custom solution after all the time and effort of configuration and debugging.

Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: Are you able to set up double-writing in your application code? I'm basically thinking: set up double writing, set up a vanilla Linux box in Azure and install PG there, set up tds_fdw from *that* PG pointing at the SQL-Server-on-Azure tables, and then set up postgres_fdw from azure PG pointing to your PG. Then you backfill the previously-written records with `INSERT INTO the_table_in_azure_pg SELECT * FROM the_foreign_table WHERE id < (first ID already present in the table from double-writing)`

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I definitely prefer a solution based on federated SQL over a custom tool, because then I can easily build the incremental upsertion logic.

Comment: I have a similar situation at work except that the data is getting pushed into Oracle. In the end we chose to grab bacpac files, parse them and load the result. Parsing the bacpac files is done using a utility that wrote for that purpose: https://github.com/gsiems/bac-tract. There is the start of a util for creating pg_dump files but I've never gotten to the point of actually testing it.

Comment: @N8allan did gsiemes's comment can answer your question?

Comment: @LeonYue, it's an interesting approach, but I ended up building my own simple replication system.

Comment: @N8allan congratulations. it will be better that if you could share us something as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you solved your problem. It will be better that if you could share us more detail about your simple replication system.